# Testing if VCR supports S-Video by image comparison. Is it correct?

Tags: video-quality, video-recording, cable, vhs

When I capture a video from my VCR (a Sharp VC-M401SM) with an S-Video cable connected to a SCART adaptor (like the one shown in [this post](https://video.stackexchange.com/q/29933/29303)) I obtain a gray-scale image.

One possibility for this is that the VCR is not capable to output an S-Video signal. To understand if this was the true reason I compared some couples of images composed by:

- the gray-scale image obtained using the S-Video cable;
- an image obtained by acquiring a colored image from the composite signal and then converted to grayscale.

Here is one example:

[image: First image]

[image: Second image]

It seems to me that there are little differences between the two images. I guess that these differences result from noise and from color to gray-scale conversion. This makes me think that the quality of the images is comparable.

Therefore I conclude that the gray-scale output when using the S-Video cable is not due a problem in the croma component, but instead due to the fact that the VCR does not support the S-Video output.

#### Questions

- Is my reasoning correct? Can we conclude from this test that the VCR does not support S-Video?
- If not, what can we conclude instead?

Comment: You are likely comparing the same signal against itself, see https://allpinouts.org/pinouts/cables/audio_video/scart-to-rca-and-s-video-adapter/ - SCART pin 19 carries the identical signal to both connectors. So it's a question of whether SCART pin 15 (chrominance) is carrying any signal.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just checked that the SCART pin 15 was not cabled inside the VCR. So I conclude that the differences in the two images above is only due to noise.